# Windows Server 2012 R2 , can I repair Office 365 Pro Plus?

Tags: windows, microsoft-office-365

I need to repair Office 365 Pro Plus on Windows Server 2012 R2. On a normal Office 365 Business on Windows 10 you go to programs, search for Office 365 Business, and it gives you two options, 1 is uninstall and the other one is Change.  When you click change Office 365 Business opens automatically the Office Repair portal and then you can choose between Quick repair and Full Repair. This is not the case for this Office 365 Pro Plus on Windows Server 2012 R2.

My question: is there is any way I can Repair Office 365 Pro Plus without a complete reinstallation?

Comment: `This is not the case for this Office 365 Pro Plus on Windows Server 2012 R2`. What does it do? Is Office 365 ProPlus present in Add/Remove Programs control panel?

Comment: yes, is present on the add/remove, if a click on the Change...it is Start uninstalling everything

Comment: Unfortunately, [Office 365 is not supported](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=2111390) on Windows Server 2012 R2, so unexpected behaviour can occur.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Start repair from CLI : “C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\ClientX64\OfficeClickToRun.exe” scenario=Repair platform=x86 culture=en-us scenario=Repair DisplayLevel=True

Comment: Check this registry key: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\O365ProPlusRetail - en-us` for value: `NoModify`. If running 32-bit Office, it may be here: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\O365ProPlusRetail - en-us`